# How to get variable handle using dlsym?

Tags: variables, dlsym

How to get variable from shared library?
I get error library.so udefined symbol: ...
but actually symbol is defined in shared library.

Comment: Please provide more details: what library ? What language ? What compiler options ? A minimal reproductible code snippet to have the error ?

Comment: specific library for device xxx_library.so.2
language с
compiler gcc
options -ldl -lm -lpthread
I can operate with library functions, but can`t operate with variables
example
uint32 *variable_name;

Comment: specific library for device xxx_library.so.2
language с,
compiler gcc,
options -ldl -lm -lpthread,
I can operate with library functions, but can`t operate with variables
example
uint32 *variable_handle;
variable_handle = dlsym(lib_handle, "NAME");

dlerror returns error .....xxx_library.so.2: undefined symbol: NAME